# "Cannot locate resource 'mainwindow.xaml'." upon UI culture change

Tags: c#, wpf, localization

I have a program setup like this:

- Logic/interaction project
- Example UI project (simple view and not much else)

The logic/interaction project has resource files for various different languages (e.g 'Resources.de.resx', 'Resources.ja.resx' etc...), whereas the example project only has a single resource file ('Resources.resx').

The example project can run and launch just fine without modification, but when I add the following line into the example project:

```
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr");
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
System.IO.IOException: 'Cannot locate resource '<resource-name>.xaml'
```

Where  changes depending on the location that I put the line into the project.

I'm not really sure the ramifications of changing the UI culture, or particularly how resource files and localisation works - so any pointers as to why a change of localisation could be causing resource errors would be very helpful.

Comment: @Vlad we're using WPF (I've updated the tags)

Comment: Where and how are you referencing "<resource-name>.xaml" in your code? Please remember to always provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking a question.

Comment: @mm8 The xaml files that bring up the errors are referenced inside of other XAML files/views. The XAML files themselves are just files available in the solution explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing or misconfigured the `NeutralResourcesLanguage` setting in the file `AssemblyInfo.cs`. Open the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file a look for that setting. You will normally see the following comment:

```
//In order to begin building localizable applications, set
//<UICulture>CultureYouAreCodingWith</UICulture> in your .csproj file
//inside a <PropertyGroup>.  For example, if you are using US english
//in your source files, set the <UICulture> to en-US.  Then uncomment
//the NeutralResourceLanguage attribute below.  Update the "en-US" in
//the line below to match the UICulture setting in the project file.

//[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]
```

So you must **uncomment the latest line defining the NeutralResourcesLanguage** and make sure that the language code in that line matches your neutral language exactly. So, for instance, if you chose `"fr"` as the neutral language in your application you can't set there `"fr-FR"` and viceversa.

The second parameter tells the application where to find resources not included in the localized resource DLL. The two available options are:

- UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite: look for the missing resources in the neutral language resource DLL. This is the option you must select if you chose to have your neutral language in a resource DLL (the same name, but with no language tag). This is quite likely the option you need.
- UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.MainAssembly: this option is needed when you don't have a satellite dll with the neutral language and everything is kept in the main assembly.

In my case I had already included that setting but I made two mistakes: I had defined my neutral language to be `es-ES` but I set there only `es`, and I didn't specify the fallback mode to be `Satellite`, so I guess the default value it takes when not defined is `MainAssembly`.

Comment: Apologies but I wont be able to verify this as I moved on from this work a while ago, but this definitely sounds like where I went wrong - so I'll mark it as accepted